# fgets() doesn't recognize all Inputs. Any ideas what im doing wrong?

Tags: c, fgets

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int size = 0;
    do
    {
        printf("Put in size of the list (Range[1;2^16-1]): ");
        scanf("%d", &size);//input
        if (size <= 0)
            printf("Put in a correct length!\n");
    } while (size <= 0);
    char temp[size+1];
    while (fgets(temp, size, stdin))//break with ^Z or ^D
    {
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)//output
    {
        printf("%c", temp[i]);
        printf("%d", i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Put in size of the list (Range[1;2^16-1]): 5
pizza
^Z(my powershell input)
a012z34
```

I tried to use the `fgets()` function but it doesnt recognize all chars, only the last two chars. So I did some research but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: second argument to `fgets` should be `sizeof temp`  (you cut it short by 1). Also the first thing `fgets` read will be the newline character left behind from inputting the size

Comment: what inputs should it recognize?

Comment: @M.M is referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input)

Comment: What do you mean by "recognize"? No matter what input you get, you print exactly `size` character plus the integer value.

Comment: Ah, I see, the comment generating the manual `EOF` threw me off - it's at least called once.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few issues:

1. You do not consume the trailing `\n` from your `scanf` call.
   That leads to your first `fgets` reading only `"\n"`. This is clearly not what you would want but as you run `fgets` in a loop it does not cause problems.
2. You provide a size to `fgets` that does not match your buffer and cannot hold your input.
   Your buffer is 6 bytes but you only provide 5 to `fgets`.
   5 Bytes are not enough to hold `"pizza"` as there is no room for `\0`. It also does not hold the `\n` for that line.
   This means you will first get `"pizz"` and immediately afterwards you will get `"a\n\0"`. The remaining 3 bytes from the buffer will be unchanged ans still hold `"z\0"` from previous call.
3. After you end with `^D` you print the content. But for values `\n`, `\0` etc. you will not see something that you typed. That is why you don't see anything between your numbers.

You could make all input visible by printing like this:
`printf("%d: '%c' (%d)\n", i, temp[i], temp[i]);`

Solution:
If you want to get input with up to 5 characters, you need a buffer of 7 bytes and you must provide that size to `fgets`.